# How to verify that GCP Cloud Billing is disabled with programmatic budget disabling?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, billing

I'm new to GCP, and I'm trying to enable a kill switch to cap billing. There's a GCP article on this, [Cap (disable) billing to stop usage](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage), but after following it (and other online tutorials), I'm still having issues.

As the article instructs, I have:

- Enabled the Cloud Billing API
- Set up a budget ("kill-switch") to monitor costs of my project, connecting it to my `budget-kill-switch` Pub/Sub topic
- Written a cloud function with the [given Node.js code](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#write-a-cloud-function-2) for the `package.json` and `index.js`, also setting the `GCP_PROJECT` environment variable to my project and the entry point to "stopBilling"
- Configured the Cloud Function service account to have a Billing Account Administrator role through the [Account Management page](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#update-cloud-billing-permissions) of the Cloud Billing console

Then, the [Validating that Cloud Billing is disabled](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#validate-that-cloud-billing-is-disabled) step fails. I manually published a message in Pub/Sub under my `budget-kill-switch` Pub/Sub topic, using the [given Pub/Sub message body](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#test-your-cloud-function) to test, just modifying the "budgetDisplayName" to match mine:

```
{
    "budgetDisplayName": "kill-switch",
    "alertThresholdExceeded": 1.0,
    "costAmount": 100.01,
    "costIntervalStart": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "budgetAmount": 100.00,
    "budgetAmountType": "SPECIFIED_AMOUNT",
    "currencyCode": "USD"
}
```

I get a "Message delivered." confirmation pop-up. But, when I go [view my billing accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing), the billing account that should have been disabled is still there. The article says that

> The project will no longer be visible under the Cloud Billing account and resources in the project are disabled, including the Cloud Function if it's in the same project.

**Questions**:

- Should the the Pub/Sub subscriber (the budget's one) be type push or pull? It seems like the default is pull, but when I change it to pull and manually pull the test message through, the Cloud Billing account is still there.

Note: When I change the subscriber to pull, and I pull the messages through, I see that the auto-generated ones also have attributes in the message, ie `billingAccountId`, `budgetId`, and `schemaVersion`. I've also tried adding attributes to the test Pub/Sub message but this didn't work.

- Could this be due to my still being on the free trial period?
- Any ideas/suggestions as to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest that you contact [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing)

Comment: Thanks, I did reach out to Billing Support, but they just refer you back to manually disabling billing, which I don't want to do. Tbh it seems like it's in their best interests to keep this whole process a bit convoluted.